# Adding records to a relations repository with Laravel

Tags: laravel, repository, laravel-5.5

I’m using laravel 5.5 and andersao/l5-repository. I want to add an answer record with the question repository.

My Question Controller

```
 protected $repository;

public function __construct(QuestionRepository $repository)
        {
            $this->repository = $repository;
        }



 public function add_answer(AnswerAddRequest $request)
        {
            $this->validator->with($request->all())->passesOrFail(ValidatorInterface::RULE_CREATE);

            $question = $this->repository->answer->create([
                'content'     => 'Answer text question',
                'user_id'     => Auth::user()->id
            ]);


            return question;
        }
```

My Question Model

```
 public function answer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Answer::class, 'question_id');
    }
```

I tried '$this->repository->answer()'

always error : Undefined property

I think I have to use the with() method, but I don’t want to take all the content. I only need to add content with the relation of the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add this part of code

```
public function answer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Answer::class, 'question_id');
}
```

into your Question mode, not into your repository.
The Laravel Eloquent class extends the Model class, which has methods like belongsTo that you're using.

--- EDIT ---

If you want to use repository, you could integrate it with Eloquent:

```
$this->reposotiry->find($request->input('question_id'))->answer()->create([
 'content'     => 'Answer text question',
 'user_id'     => Auth::user()->id
]);
```

Comment: you right, I wrote wrong repository section. It's code in my model. I edited my question.

Comment: But your repository doens't have the method 'anwser'

Comment: And I think, it's better to use the Eloquent model directly, instead of the repository, except if you have a reason to do that.